# Futures Exchanges and marking to market

Tags: derivatives

When a futures exchange marks to the market, does it "help" the losing side or winning side. According to my knowledge, it makes the losing side lose even more by deducting from their margin account? If that is the case, doesn't it increase the default risk?

Answer (score 2):

You need to read some basic books about futures.  If you buy a futures contract and it goes down , the exchange demands variation margin.  That IS the loss.  There is no doubling up.  I don't understand the question about default risk.  Default of whom ?